# Unable to read the metadata of AndroidManifest.xml in unit test cases

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing local unit testcases for my android application.
In one of the test cases, i need to read the contents of metadata defined in the AndroidManifest.xml

I can easily read the data by calling these methods - metadata.getString() / metadata.getBoolean()
while running the application

I Cannot access the same in unit testing.
the values of the all the keys defined in maifest appears to be null here.

In the below code, object **ai is created properly, 
res is null,
aM is null,**

**metadata is not null and it has the values for hub_url, enable_transmission and authentication as defined in manifest file.**

**Its strange that when i try to access contents of metadata in variable a, b and c, all are null**

```
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    val ai = context!!.packageManager.getApplicationInfo( context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    val res = ai.metaData.getBoolean( context.getString(R.string.enable_transmission))

    val aM = ai.metaData.get( context.getString(R.string.enable_transmission))
    val metadata = ai.metaData!!;

    val a = metadata.getString(context.getString(R.string.hub_url))
    val b = metadata.get(context.getString(R.string.enable_transmission));
    val c = metadata.get(context.getString(R.string.authentication));
```

Here is the manifest file content

```
 <application>

    <meta-data
        android:resource="@string/basic"
        android:name="@string/authentication"
        android:value="@string/basic" />

    <meta-data
        android:resource="@string/hub_url"
        android:name="@string/hub_url"
        android:value="@string/hub_url" />

    <meta-data
        android:resource="@bool/enable"
        android:name="@string/enable_transmission"
        android:value="@bool/enable" />


</application>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant AndroidManifest code?

Comment: @shkschneider yes i added the manifest file contents above

Comment: Have you checked for `context.packageName` having the correct string?

Comment: @tynn yes. package name is proper as expected.

Comment: try, remove android:resource and get value

Comment: @Pratik18 yes previously i had not included the resource attribute. yet the same issue was produced.
I tried adding resources attribute to see if there is any change with the metadata, But no. The attributes of metadata are null with or without resource attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
val  context = applicationContext
val ai = context!!.packageManager.getApplicationInfo( context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
val metadata = ai.metaData!!
val res = metadata.get( context.getString(R.string.enable_transmission))
val aM = metadata.get(context.getString(R.string.enable_transmission))
```

In manifest meta-data tag only using android:value not using android:resource than object direct convert in particular format.